# Tilawat voice of Surat Ar-Raĥmān

Tags: qiraat

I was listening to a beautiful tilawat and I don't know who recite it can anyone tell me the name of person who recite this http://quran.com/55.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a specific recitation of Quran.

Comment: I know that but There is no chat room to ask this question and I don't know the other way to do it?

Comment: Chat room link you can find on top left corner in the drop down menu next to "Islam"

Comment: I have been using stackover flow from quite a while and i know where chat room options are but there are only four of those and  everyone is empty!

Comment: @Hamza click on the Stack Exchange network menu and you will see chat along with links to meta and the blog. The reciter is Tawfeeq as-Sayegh (or as-Sawa'igh).

Comment: thanks I know how to open chat room but i just wanted to know the reciter thank.